# Scraping pagination with the same pagination links

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination

I am trying to scrape stock information from this link: https://www.affarsvarlden.se/bors/kurslistor/stockholm-large/kurs/

It works well for the first 100 rows with `requests` in python, but the remaining rows are hidden under the pagination element. The question is how I can get these as well. What makes it difficult is that the link to the second page (containing the remaining rows) is the same as for the first one, and that I can't see that any requests are made when changing between the two when looking in the Networks tab in Developer tools. Is there any way to do this using the `requests` module or do I need to use something like `selenium`? I couldn't get the latter to work either.

I would really appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, all the data is already upload to the page when request to page. So, you can try this,

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests
import json

url = 'https://www.affarsvarlden.se/bors/kurslistor/stockholm-large/kurs/'
resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.findAll('script'):
    content = tag.get_text()

    if '__INITIAL_STATE__' not in content:
        continue

    index = content.find('{')
    data = json.loads(content[index:])
    df = json_normalize(data['stocklist']['stockholm-large/kurs/'], 'info')
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly (except that I had to move the if-statement to be after the assignment of content).

Comment: Oh, so sorry, I edited. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with selenium. The script below will open the webpage and go to the next page.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# navigate to webpage
driver.get('https://www.affarsvarlden.se/bors/kurslistor/stockholm-large/kurs/')

# next button path
next_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="canvas"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ul/li[4]/a')

# Clicking button throws error the fist time
try:
    next_button.click()
    pass
except Exception:
    next_button.click()
```

Edit: Your are going to need chromedriver.exe in your working directory to use webdriver.